# SQL Query Using Then(?) Or a points system

Tags: sql, search, sorting, sql-order-by

I am building a user search and I have a Users table with id, first, and last in it.

I then query a names, say: "John Smith".

Using PHP I'll break the query into 2 parts: q1 = John and q2 = Smith.

I want to devise a points system where the record that has first = John and last = Smith gets pulled to the top.

So my sql is something like this:

```
 SELECT User.id, User.first, User.last
 FROM users as User
 WHERE (User.first = q1 OR User.first = q2) OR //if this is true +1 points
 WHERE (User.last = q1 OR User.last = q2) OR //if this is true +1 points

//then sum up the points and order by it (so the User.id with John Smith will have 2 points)
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: `sum (case when .... then 1 else 0 end)` should do the trick

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your DBMS has an IF function you can do:

```
SELECT User.id, User.first, User.last,
    IF (User.first = q1 OR User.first = q2, 1, 0) +
    IF (User.last = q1 OR User.last = q2, 1, 0) as points
FROM users as User
ORDER BY points DESC
```

Comment: that'll work, but how do i stop the ones with 0 points from showing up in the result set?

Comment: that's what I thought but strangely enough i get this: Unknown column 'points' in 'where clause'

Comment: Oh, sorry, you have to use `HAVING points > 0` in cases like this.